# Unknown interface in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, network-interface

I want to refresh the network interface by turning it down then up as per some recommendations to get DNS updates. 
I listed the interfaces in my device using: `ifconfig -a`. I got 3 interfaces and I am concerned about the wired one. The output is (hardware addresses are omitted with xx):

```
x@x-device:~$ ifconfig
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:172.17.72.13  Bcast:172.17.79.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/xx Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26493098 (26.4 MB)  TX bytes:7035908 (7.0 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:ef200000-ef220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:138063 (138.0 KB)  TX bytes:138063 (138.0 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I then run the command:

```
sudo ifdown enp0s31f6 && sudo ifup enp0s31f6
```

But the output:

```
Unknown interface enp0s31f6
```

What is the problem?

Comment: That’s most likely not the complete name. Don’t use legacy tools like `ifconfig`. Instead, use the `ip` command from the iproute2 suite.

Comment: Are you using Desktop Environment on this machine? Do you have installed NetworkManager on it?

Comment: @mariacz It is Desktop. But I have not installed anything specific for network managing. Just the default system.

Comment: @Daniel B Sorry can you provide more specific answer (full command)?

Comment: You can list network links with `ip link`. If you want to see addresses, too, use `ip addr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 ip link set up dev enp0s31f6
```

and then run dhcp-client or setup IP manually

```
man ip
```

Comment: You mean run dhcp-client to set up the DNS?

Comment: If you use dhcp for network interface configuration - run/restart dhcp client for this interface. If you have static IP addresses, you should set the network configuration manually.